# Fill half of fft(x) array with conjugate before ifft

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, scipy, fft

Let `x` be a (real-valued) array of length N. I have done some modifications (filtering, etc.)  in the frequency-domain  on `X=fft(x)`.

Before doing inverseFFT (`y=ifft(X)`), I would like that the **second half** of `X` is filled with conjugate of the first half of `X`, in reverse order. Why ? Because it must be like that for real signals! (see: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fast_Fourier_transform#FFT_algorithms_specialized_for_real_and.2For_symmetric_data)

How can I do this with Python ?
Should it be something like this ?

```
X[N/2:N] = np.conjugate(X[N/2::-1])
```

Comment: Why don't you just make the modifications to both halves?

Comment: I do lots of modifications tests by trial and error, so it's easier to make the modifications only in the first half , and replicate the second half of `fft` at the end.

Comment: uhm, why not just use the [real transforms](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/routines.fft.html)? This is exactly what they are designed for (well, specifically, optimising for known real data).

Comment: Yes @HenryGomersall, I know that real transforms may be more adapted for that. But I don't like to use them : I like the fact that `fft` of an N-array is a N-array, (and not a 2N? 2N-1? N/2?-array with realfft), etc.
It is simpler in my mind to deal always with standard `fft`

Comment: So you're saying you want to take the full length FFT rather than the real FFT because you explicitly want the full length, but you want a technique for coping with the fact that now you have the full length because you don't want to actually _work_ with the full length? This seems like a pretty inane position.

Comment: I like the fact that an N-array produces an N-array with both `fft` and `ifft`. I find it simpler in my mind and in the code... I know it's not optimized, but...

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if it's 100% correct, but

```
X = fft(x)
N = len(x)

# here do some modifications on X (in the frequency domain)

X[:N/2:-1]=np.conjugate(X[1:N/2])
y=ifft(X)
```

seems to work : the modifications done on the first half of X will be replicated on the second half of X. Then `y` will be the (real-valued) output.